# Xquery string-join function

Tags: xquery

I am having this piece of code:

```
<Statuses>{"<![CDATA[[Status] = ",string-join($ListOfStatus/Status,"' OR [Status] = '"),"']]>" }</Statuses>
```

I need to get an element like:

```
<Statuses><![CDATA[[Status] = 'Pending' OR [Status] = 'Submitted']]></Statuses>
```

but I am also getting a blank character between the first quote and the first status (' Pending instead of 'Pending, and another one between the last status and last quote, hence Submitted ' instead of Submitted'.

Does anyone know how to get rid of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your expression is returning is a sequence of strings, which are output separated by spaces. If you want to concatenate them into a single string, use `concat`:

```
<Statuses>{concat("<![CDATA[[Status] = '",string-join($ListOfStatus/Status,"' OR [Status] = '"),"']]>")}</Statuses>
```

However, note that adding the CDATA declarations inside a string is not the same as creating a CDATA decorated text node.